# Using Python/Pandas to merge rows that have similar values but combine data that is different to a single row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I've been digging through stack overflow trying to solve a problem, I come close ever time, but I don't get exactly what I need.
(this is generic csv file, I made up for the example)
something.csv

```
lastName, firstName, address, tool, description
Franks, James, 321 Hammond, hammer, "It hammers"
Franks, James, 321 Hammond, nails, "It Nails stuff"
Phiilips, Tom, 773 James St, mower, "It mows"
Phiilips, Tom, 773 James St, weed-wacker, "It whacks"}
```

**I'm trying to merge the lines into a dictionary to where they read something like this**

```
Franks: [(hammer, "It hammers"), (nails, "It Nails stuff")]
Phiilips: [(mower, "It mows"),  (weed-wacker, "It whacks")]
```

I'm wondering if this is even possible, or I'm just making things too hard...

**This is what I've tried so far**

```
df3 = pd.read_csv("results.csv", encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
df3.groupby("lastname")[["tool","description"]].apply(lambda g: list(map(tuple, g.values.tolist()))).to_dict()
```

---

**The Results:**

```
{Franks: [("hammer", "It hammers"), ("nails", "It Nails stuff")]}
{Franks: [("hammer", "It hammers"), ("nails", "It Nails stuff")]}
{Phiilips:[("mower", "It mows"), ("weed-wacker", "It whacks")]}
{Phiilips:[("mower", "It mows"), ("weed-wacker", "It whacks")]}
```

---

> Not good enough yet to figure out why I'm getting duplicate lines, but
>   something like this without the duplicate lines is what I am aiming
>   for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module and its `DictReader`.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
with open('results.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        dd[row['lastName']].append((row['tool'], row['description']))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'Franks': [('hammer', 'It hammers'), ('nails', 'It Nails stuff')],
         'Phiilips': [('mower', 'It mows'), ('weed-wacker', 'It whacks')]})
```

Comment: I'm getting the same output as the result I posted above:  

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Franks': [('hammer', 'It hammers'), ('nails', 'It Nails stuff')])
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Franks': [('hammer', 'It hammers'), ('nails', 'It Nails stuff')])
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Phiilips': [('mower', 'It mows'), ('weed-wacker', 'It whacks')])
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Phiilips': [('mower', 'It mows'), ('weed-wacker', 'It whacks')]) . 
  
How do i just get the single result of each line?

Comment: @VanPatton But that's not the same output???  `dd['Franks']` returns `[('hammer', 'It hammers'), ('nails', 'It Nails stuff')]`, like you'd expect, and the same for `dd['Phiilips']`

Comment: After seeing the rest of your comment, I'd guess you have an extra `for` loop somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Glad I could help!